# unable to run script to create multiple database in docker

Tags: postgresql, macos, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create multiple databases in one container. I am following the [link](https://github.com/mrts/docker-postgresql-multiple-databases/blob/master/create-multiple-postgresql-databases.sh)

With some reason, I don't see initdb shell script running for me

docker-compose looks like

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: employee
      POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: employee_test
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
      - "./initdb.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sh"
      - "./.docker_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

I started by POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: employee,employee_test but I got an error that employee database is already created.

shell script

```
function create_user_and_database() {
    local database=$1
    echo "  Creating user and database '$database'"
    psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$database"<<-EOSQL
        CREATE DATABASE $database;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $database TO $POSTGRES_USER;
EOSQL
}


if [ -n "$POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES" ]; then
  PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    echo "Multiple database creation requested: $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES"
    for db in $(echo $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES | tr ',' ' '); do
        create_user_and_database $db
    done
    echo "Multiple databases created"
fi
```

When I run the script directly it complains about

```
  Creating user and database 'employee_test'
psql: FATAL:  database "employee_test" does not exist
```

Not sure, id the create database command run or not. Can someone help what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you mount backup volume it will not run the `init` script of DB creation.

So you have two option

- Remove backup volume and run the `init` script.
- Add the init script data to your back volume

If you check the [entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres) or docker logs you will see

```
Recreating postgres ... 
WARNING: Service "postgres" is using volume "/var/lib/postgresql/data" from the previous container. Host mapping.....
```

So the init script will ignore during startup due to the backup volume